# How to select a subset of a dataframe using a variable dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, pca

I have an R dataframe with 300 columns.
I have done Principal Component Analysis and grabbed the top 110 columns that explain the variability of dataset.
How do we pass the 110 column names list to an R function to select the subset of original dataframe containing only these columns?

Please see the code below.

```r
t.df = read.xlsx('t_dataset.xlsx', 1,startRow=1 )
X=t.df[ , 3:307]
t.pca=PCA(X, graph=FALSE)
write.infile(t.pca$var$contrib, "pca.csv", sep=',')

t.df.pca = read.xlsx('pca1.xlsx', 1,startRow=1 )
t.df.pca.r=subset(t.df.pca, Dim.1>mean(Dim.1) | Dim.2>mean(Dim.2) | Dim.3>mean(Dim.3) | Dim.4>mean(Dim.4) | Dim.5>mean(Dim.5))

c1=c(t.df.pca.r$Column)

#c1 contains the list of 110 column names.

c2=cat(paste(shQuote(c1), collapse=", "))
print(c2)
```

output of print(c2):
"funct", "pronoun", "ppron", "i", "we", "you", "shehe", "they", "ipron", "article", "verb", "auxverb", "past", "present", "future", "adverb", "conj", upto 110 variables

```r
t.df.2=t.df[c(c2)]
nrow(t.df.2)
ncol(t.df.2)

t.df.4=t.df[c2]
nrow(t.df.4)
ncol(t.df.4)

t.df.5=t.df[ ,c2]
nrow(t.df.5)
ncol(t.df.5)
```

Above code returns the result as follows:
[1] 45498
[1] 0

[1] 45498
[1] 0

[1] 45498
[1] 0

What I need is: Pass these column names to an R function and get a subset of the original dataframe t.df. This subset will contain only the 110 columns present in c1

How to do this?

Comment: Simply subset with extract `[` function: `orig_df[vector_of_column_names]`.

Comment: Srikrishna Krishnarao, all of the comments and the answer so far are saying two things: (1) just use `[`, using the vector of column names as you say you want to, ala `t.df[,c2]`; and (2) I think you might do well to spend a moment or two reading through [`?Extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/Extract) as well as several good tutorials on indexing matrices and frames in R, as it appears as if this is a straight-forward application. If we are completely wrong, you'll need to convince us otherwise, as it does look like it's just that. Good luck!

Comment: I've posted all the forms I've tried. Indeed it looks very simple, however, I've no clue why the desired output is not received.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, with an example data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
    col2 = c(2, 3, 4),
    col3 = c(3, 4, 5)
  )

cols_to_keep <- c("col1", "col3")

df %>% 
  select(cols_to_keep)
```

I don't know what format your data is in, but as long as you get a vector of column names you should be able to use the `select` command.

Comment: You can achieve same result using base R without loading whole `tidyverse` environment: `subset(mtcars, select = c(am, cyl))`

Comment: Try `t.df[ , c1]`  Incidentally, your second line could read `X <- t.df[ , 3:307]`  There is no need for `1:nrow(t.df)`.  You might find it useful to learn basic indexing of dataframes using [ , ].

Comment: I edited my question to show my list of column variables. Instead of calling c("col1", "col3"), I need to pass a variable in place such as c(x) and x is obtained from previous step as shown above